# Any eclipse plug-in for intel fortran compiler?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, fortran, intel-fortran

I've recently installed Intel FORTRAN compiler 11 on Linux. On its installation path, there is a folder named eclipse plug-ins. Taking a look at Intel website, I cannot find any homepage for this plug-in. I wonder if anyone has already installed Intel Fortran 11 plug-in for eclipse. If yes, how it should be installed? I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315012/eclipse-with-intel-fortran-debugger) as well. it is about idb not the compiler.

Comment: Don't know for sure. I know of [Photran][1] ... which (so I've heard) works nicely. 
  [1]: http://www.eclipse.org/photran/

Comment: Thanks. But I need to compile my app under intel fortran. Is there any graphical IDE for Intel fortran under Linux?

Comment: @hsalimi: Photran does support the Intel Fortran compiler. And yes, it also works on Linux.

Comment: @hsalimi - Yes, as janneb said. It is made with that in mind.

Comment: @Janneb: Write your comment as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Photran](http://www.eclipse.org/photran/) is the Fortran IDE plugin for Eclipse. It supports most widely used compilers, including the Intel Fortran compiler.